# What is the code in this "table.rows.add"?

Tags: c#

[error table.Rows.Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzo8x.png)

> what code do I need and where to I put it pls help me.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (QtyTb.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("Enter The Quantity of Products");
        else if (flag == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Select The Product");
        else
        {
            
            num = num + 1;
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(QtyTb.Text);
            totprice = qty * uprice;                             
            table.Rows.Add(num, qty, uprice, totprice);
            OrderGv.DataSource = table;
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First you declare table and add column after you input in table. here you can't input without table definition.

Comment: The error is pretty clear… `table` does not have four (4) columns.

Comment: It's also not very clear why you have this: `OrderGv.DataSource = table;` there. Why would you set the DataSource now? That needs to be set beforehand. Then just add rows (with the correct number of Columns) to the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("num", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("uprice", typeof(decimal));
 dt.Columns.Add("totprice", typeof(decimal));

dt.Rows.Add(num, qty, uprice, totprice);
```